# details for project could not be loaded

Tags: .net, visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2017

My first attempt with F# has yielded with the following exceptions:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The operation
>   failed as details for project ConsoleApp1 could not be loaded.
>   Error     Assets file
>   'C:\Users\asmith\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp1\obj\project.assets.json'
>   not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this
>   file. ConsoleApp1 C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets 327 
>   Error     Assets file
>   'C:\Users\asmith\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp1\obj\project.assets.json'
>   not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this
>   file. ConsoleApp1 C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets 167

The following is the code that generated the above exceptions:

```
    // Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org

open System



type Credentials = {user:string;domain:string;pass:string}


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "Hello World from F#!"
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I've received the following input after issuing update-package 0reinstall command:

> > Each package is licensed to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party
> >     packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by
> >     additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine
> >     any dependencies.
>
> Package Manager Console Host Version 4.5.0.4685
>
> Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.
>
> PM> update-package -reinstall No package updates are available from
>   the current package source for project 'ConsoleApp1'. update-package :
>   The operation failed as details for project ConsoleApp1 could not be
>   loaded. At line:1 char:1
>   + update-package -reinstall
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
>   Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.2036449 PM>

Comment: try "dotnet restore" from the command line or package manager console